# twitter bootstrap not working as expected with react

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use twitter bootstrap with react.
I have the below code:

```
import { Container, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';

const SignUpComponent = ({ history }: { [key: string]: any }) => (
  <>
    <Container fluid>
      
      <Row>
       <Col lg={4} md={4}>xxx</Col>
       <Col lg={4} md={4}>yyy</Col>
       <Col lg={4} md={4}>zzz</Col>

      </Row>
    </Container>
  </>
 
);
```

I was expecting it to be in 3 columns on screen, but I see the below output.

```
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

instead of

```
xxx yyy zzz
```

I am unable to debug why this is happening. Can anybody help why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

`index.tsx` file needs to have the below import

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```